# Randomizing object choosing with tags in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make color switch in unity but I am making it different. 
 **How do I make unity to choose between random color that has been specified with tags and delete the object, regenerate and again select random object and delete after timer of 5 seconds?

[Here is the image of what I have done till now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl9iK.png)**

I have tried this script but it doesn't work

```
private IList<GameObject> m_TargetsList;
void Start()
{
     m_TargetsArray = new IList<GameObject>();
     //populate the list, either by searching for Tag or Adding to 
     the List from the target list.
 }
 void ChooseRandomTarget()
 {
     int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, m_TargetsArray.Count);

     //pass in the game object into your MoveToward() method
     MoveToward(m_TargetsArray[randomIndex]);
 }
```

Comment: [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)?

Comment: Can u please explain more briefly

Answer (score 0):

You should call the MoveToward() method inside Update().

```
public float moveSpeed;
void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,m_TargetsArray[randomIndex].position,moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: ok. I need to delete the object at a timer of 5 second but i dont understand how to add it over here

Comment: and the object need t obe regenerated after sometime